# Attachment reposition breaks player

Tags: lua, roblox

In this grappling hook script, I’m attempting to project the rope towards the right arm of the player character. The goal is to have the player character move towards the target once the grappling hook has been launched and connected.

Currently, I’ve managed to get the rope to project correctly and the player still retains the ability to rotate. However, I’m encountering an issue where the player character remains stationary and does not move towards the target as intended.

Here’s the code I’m working with:

```
local Player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
local RightArm = Player.Character:WaitForChild("Right Arm")
local Mouse = Player:GetMouse()
local Debounce = false
local mouseDown = false

local Max_Distance = 1000 -- This is the max length that the grapple hook can get to
local WinchSpeed = 200 -- Winch Speed.
local RopeVisible = true -- Is the rope visible?
local RopeColor = BrickColor.new("Black")

-- Calculate the distance between two Vector3 objects and round to the nearest ten
local function distance_between_vectors(u, v)
    local difference = u - v
    local distance = difference.Magnitude
    distance = math.floor(distance / 1 + 0.5) * 1
    return distance
end

local function Attachment(method, parent)
    if method == "Create" then
        local Attachment = Instance.new("Attachment")
        Attachment.Parent = parent
    else
        parent.Attachment:Destroy()
    end
end

Mouse.Button1Up:Connect(function()
    mouseDown = false
end)

Mouse.Button1Down:Connect(function()
    mouseDown = true
    if Debounce == false then
        Debounce = true
        local HitPosition = Mouse.Hit.p
        local distance = distance_between_vectors(HitPosition, RightArm.Position)
        if distance <= Max_Distance then 
            local NewPart = Instance.new("Part") 
            NewPart.Anchored = true 
            NewPart.Parent = game.Workspace 
            NewPart.Position = HitPosition 
            NewPart.Transparency = 1
            Attachment("Create", NewPart)
            Attachment("Create", RightArm)
            local Rope = Instance.new("RopeConstraint")
            Rope.Parent = NewPart
            Rope.Attachment0 = NewPart.Attachment
            Rope.Attachment1 = RightArm.Attachment
            Rope.WinchEnabled = true
            Rope.WinchTarget = 5
            Rope.WinchForce = 1000000
            Rope.Restitution = 0
            Rope.Color = RopeColor
            Rope.Visible = RopeVisible
            Rope.Length = distance / 2
            Rope.WinchSpeed = WinchSpeed

            -- Play sound
            local SoundId = "rbxassetid://4780469887" 
            local Sound = Instance.new("Sound")
            Sound.SoundId = SoundId
            Sound.Parent = RightArm
            Sound:Play()

            while mouseDown == true do
                wait()
            end

            Attachment("Destroy", NewPart)
            Attachment("Destroy", RightArm)
            NewPart.RopeConstraint:Destroy()
            NewPart:Destroy()
        end
        Debounce = false
    end
end)
```

Edit : My game only supports R6. That's why it's `RightArm`.